# Not finding coffeescript views in Rails production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm working with a rails 3.1 app. I have a comments controller that uses ajax to update the page.  There is a create.js.coffee in views/comments that should get rendered when a comment gets created.  This works just fine in the dev env, but when i run the app in production rails can't find the view.  It is like the asset pipeline isn't including it in production mode.

Code can be found here: https://github.com/samnang/ajax_rails31_demo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you need to have the `coffee-rails` gem available to the production environment. https://github.com/samnang/ajax_rails31_demo/issues/1#issuecomment-2297130

Serving JS up in requests is not supported by rails out of the box so I took another tack.

This author suggests http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/ taking full advantage of UJS.  This seems to be the trending pattern for updating the page after an xhr.  So now my controller always renders html and I use the ajax:complete callback to append the xhr.result_text.  Tip: If you haven't seen jQuery's live() method, check it out.  It is of great use with this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You have to precompile the assets as part of your deployment:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

or turn on the pipeline (which has a minor performance hit):

```
# config/environment/production.rb:
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Comment: The app doesn't even run in production without precompile, so I know I've already done that.